# image blur crossbrowser did not work with safari, opera, & ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari, cross-browser, opera

I have this code :

Js:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").css({
        "filter": "url(#example-one)", 
        "-webkit-filter": "blur(4px)", 
        "-moz-filter": "blur(4px)",
        "-o-filter": "blur(4px)",
        "-ms-filter": "blur(4px)"

    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("img").css({
            "filter": "url(#example-two)", 
            "-webkit-filter": "blur(3px)", 
            "-moz-filter": "blur(3px)",
            "-o-filter": "blur(3px)",
            "-ms-filter": "blur(3px)"

        });
    }, 3000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("img").css({
            "filter": "url(#example-three)", 
            "-webkit-filter": "blur(2px)", 
            "-moz-filter": "blur(2px)",
            "-o-filter": "blur(2px)",
            "-ms-filter": "blur(2px)"

        });
    }, 3100);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("img").css({
            "filter": "url(#example-four)", 
            "-webkit-filter": "blur(1.5px)", 
            "-moz-filter": "blur(1.5px)",
            "-o-filter": "blur(1.5px)",
            "-ms-filter": "blur(1.5px)"

        });
    }, 3200);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("img").css({
            "filter": "url(#example-five)", 
            "-webkit-filter": "blur(1px)", 
            "-moz-filter": "blur(1px)",
            "-o-filter": "blur(1px)",
            "-ms-filter": "blur(1px)"


        });
    }, 3300);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("img").css({
            "filter": "", 
            "-webkit-filter": "", 
            "-moz-filter": "",
            "-o-filter": "",
            "-ms-filter": ""

        });
    }, 3400);
    $("#promoIMG").fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="page">

    <div id="promoIMG">
        <a href="main.php"><img src="images/akb1.png" alt="" onMouseOver="this.src='images/akb2a.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/akb1.png'"/></a><br/>
        <img src="images/akb2.png" alt="AKB" />

    </div>

    <svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <!-- Filter ID/Name -->
        <filter id="example-one">

            <!-- Amount of Gaussian Blur that should be applied -->
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/>

        </filter>
        <filter id="example-two">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"/>
         </filter>
         <filter id="example-three">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
         </filter>
         <filter id="example-four">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5"/>
         </filter>
         <filter id="example-five">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
         </filter>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Tt runs perfectly in chrome and mozilla firefox, but when I try to run it on safari, opera and IE, the image blur animation did not work.

Is there something wrong in my code? or something lacking for safari, opera and IE?

Any help will be appreciated, Thx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use svg's `<image>` element instead (basically moving the image inside the svg), that should work in most browsers (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters) for support chart).